# Can a Mac OS X Menu Bar Extra be created in an Adobe AIR application?

Tags: macos, air, flash-cs5

I'm building an Adobe AIR 2.5 app that I have working the way I want in Windows in that you can minimize it to the system tray and no icon shows up in the tab order or task bar. What I'm wondering is, can you replicate this in OS X? I want there to be a menu bar extra item to show in the upper right hand corner and also be able to hide it from the Dock when running. I haven't been able find any resources and any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think what you want is possible.

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2875209

Maybe in AIR 3.0.  We'll see.